# Javascript call after innerHTML doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

When I click on a category ajax send a post request to a .php file which return a long string with the new code. Inside the returned code there's a call to a javascript function onclick="collapse(i)" where 'i' is the number of the div. In the first category, which is not retrieved by the ajax method but by the index.php the js call works meanwhile in the cat from getCat.php doesn't.
Here's the ajax call:

```
  $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: 'getCat.php',
        data: { cat: gusto },
        success: function (response) {
            document.getElementById("l-lista").innerHTML = response;
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.error(xhr);
        }
    });
```

Here's the getCat.php div with the func

```
<div class='l-container' id='$i' onclick='collapse($i)'>
```

I checked writing error and ecc but I didn't found anything. I expect the correct response like now but with the js call working.

Comment: Also, are you sure this problem is in any way related to PHP itself?

Comment: The approach you're using is flawed as it's incredibly brittle and creates a hard dependency. A better approach would be to use a delegated event handler which can listen for events on dynamically created content. See the duplicate for more information

Comment: See also: [event binding on dynamically added elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements) - though primarily for [tag:jquery] there's useful info and vanilla js solutions.